# How to return both a type predicate and an actual value from function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, predicate

I have the following function:

```
function validate(x: string | null): x is string {
  return x !== null;
}
```

How can I also return a value from this function by preserving the type predicate made in the function?

My attempt was as following:

```
function validate(x: string | null): [string, x is string] {
  const isValid = x !== null;
  return [isValid ? "valid" : "invalid", isValid];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my full usecase:

```
class Badge {
  public issuerId: string;
  public status: string;
  
  constructor(issuerId: string, status: string) {
    this.issuerId = issuerId;
    this.status = status;
  }
}

class ServiceResponse {
  public code: number;
  public message: string;
  
  constructor(code: number, message: string) {
    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

function authorizeBadge(badge: Badge | null, userId: string): ServiceResponse | undefined {
  if (!badge) {
    return new ServiceResponse(404, "badge not found");
  }

  if (badge.issuerId !== userId) {
    return new ServiceResponse(403, "unauthorized");
  }

  if (badge.status !== "SUCCESS") {
    return new ServiceResponse(423, "invalid badge state");
  }

  return;
}
```

I am using this function like following:

```
function updateBadge(badge: Badge | null, userId: string): ServiceResponse {
  const err = authorizeBadge(badge, userId);
  if (err) {
    return err
  }
  // badge here is still Badge | null

  // some business logic...
  return new ServiceResponse(200, "ok");
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What is the use case anyway? The closest approach is something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYAUAHgFyIDOUATjGAOaIA+iYI66AlGQNqU30AaRMTLgA1mDgB3MB0QBeAHyIiiGOQrVadALqIA3gChEiCAkpryANQzYFKxAEJ58lm3QBuY4ip4oIKiRudRtMLEQAfkQAcjQw6MQyaNo47GihYi4HdU1+BiUHZ1dWdh0vAF9DIA)

Comment: My usecase is much more complex than this of course. There are multiple validations within the function, and with each validation, I would like to return the specific error message from the function. And these validations of course includes null checks. And I would like this one function to use type predicates so I don't have to double check or use ! operator every time on the caller function.

Comment: You can include your actual use case so that we can check if there is anything we can do. Otherwise, your desired approach is not possible

Comment: As asked this is not possible; there's an open feature request at [ms/TS#46650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650) which would support this, but it's not part of the language.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining further if it fully addresses your question; if not, what am I missing? ... EDIT: if you're going to provide code could you make sure it's a [mre] without undeclared private/third-party things so we can play around with it in our IDEs?

Comment: @jcalz made it into minimal reproducible example. Unfortunately I will have to give the priority to wonderflame here, since he was the first one to write.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying the workaround wonderflame wrote is what you'd accept?  Or some kind of "I don't think this is possible" answer, in which case, I did the legwork to provide a source and would do further in an answer.  I suppose I'll disengage though since I don't quite get how you're deciding how comments translate into priority and I don't want to step on any toes.  My workaround for your new example looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2kLVN).  Goodbye and good luck!